# The tsp() function/object in R

Tags: r

I'm looking at the dlm() package in R.

https://github.com/cran/dlm/blob/master/R/DLM.R

In particular I am looking at the dlmForecast function:

It's using the function tsp() which I am not familiar with two examples of it's use in this function are shown below:

```
 ytsp <- tsp(y)

 newStates <- lapply(newStates, function(x) ts(x, start = ytsp[2] + 1/ytsp[3], frequency = ytsp[3]))
```

I'd like to know what the first call does and that the 1/ytsp[3] represents in the second line. Ideally a link that explains tsp() more fully would be wonderful.

All I have been able to find is this which compares their new function to tsp() without really explaining tsp().

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tframe/tframe.pdf

Baz

Comment: It would be helpful if you describe what you don't understand about the `tsp` help page (see `?tsp`).

Comment: From the help it says that tsp is the collection: c(start(x), end(x), frequency(x)). So I understand that ytsp[1]=start, ytsp[2]=end and ytsp[3] =frequency correct? Still not sure that ytsp<-tsp(y) does, does it infer these attributes from the raw data? Surely not?